# Favored Class Bonus & Custom Race

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races

**Do Custom Races made with RP Race Builder get Favored Class Bonuses? And if yes, how does one design them?** I can't find anything in that regard and even something as basic as +1 HP per level would be a major bonus for my casters (PC and Cohort).

Preferably I'm looking for an official RAW answer, but if that's not possible well respected 3PP source or D&D 3.5 source will be fine too.

Comment: I often allow players to use custom races in my game with the caveat that they won't abuse the system but I had never thought about favored class issue before so thank you for asking this question and I look forward to it receiving an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, everyone gets a Favored Class

Favored Class is a (player) character ability that has existed since the very beginning of Pathfinder 1e, as it was [introduced in the Core Rulebook](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Favored%20Class&Category=Character%20Advancement):

> Each character begins play with a single favored class of his
> choosing—typically, this is the same class as the one he chooses at
> 1st level. Whenever a character gains a level in his favored class, he
> receives either + 1 hit point or + 1 skill rank. The choice of favored
> class cannot be changed once the character is created, and the choice
> of gaining a hit point or a skill rank each time a character gains a
> level (including his first level) cannot be changed once made for a
> particular level. Prestige classes (see Chapter 11) can never be a
> favored class.

This ability has nothing to do with the (player) character's race whatsoever.

Even monsters with class levels get the Favored Class ability, i.e. they can choose a favored class and get +1 HP or 1 skill point whenever they get a class level in their favored class. [This FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nad) explicitly states this.

**Thus, you can get one of those two FCBs [Favored Class Bonus] whenever you get a level in your favored class, regardless of race.**

Also note that Favored Class is not a class feature, but a character ability (like getting a feat every odd character level). For example, if you intend to build an Arcane Trickster, you can start your 1st-level character as a Rogue yet still pick "Wizard" as your favored class, despite not having any class levels in Wizard (yet).

---

### Racial Favored Class Bonus

The Racial FCB is a new option, that was not initially available in Pathfinder, but was later [introduced in the Advanced Player's Guide](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Racial%20Favored%20Class%20Bonus&Category=Favored%20Class). These new choices are available to members of the respective races, but only as an added option to the normal FCB. They are just an addition to this already existing non-racial ability, but they are not the source of FCBs.

---

### Getting other races' FCB

There are two ways to get access to some racial FCBs.

**I: Feats**

Take the feat [Racial Heritage](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Racial%20Heritage) or [Planar Heritage](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Planar%20Heritage) and choose the race whose FCB you are interested in. This option comes with two limitations, those being that you must fulfill the prerequisite "Human" and that the race you choose must be a Humanoid / Native Outsider (depending on the feat).

The prerequisite "Human" can be fulfilled by [Humans](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Human) ofc, but also all [Half-Elves](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Half-Elf) & [Half-Orcs](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Half-Orc) qualify, as well as characters that have an ability that makes them count as Human, for example as an [Aasimar](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Aasimar) with the *Scion of Humanity* trait, a [Tiefling](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Tiefling) with the *Pass for Human* trait, or an [Ifrit](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ifrit) with the *Mostly Human* trait. There are most likely some other abilities out there that allow you to count as Human for such prerequisites, but these are the most common ones.

**II: Humanoid subtypes**

The other way is to count as a certain race due to your subtypes, but this option is limited to Humanoids. The [Race Builder rules](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Humanoid%20(0%20RP)&Category=Type%20Quality) tell us that a Humanoid with a racial subtype is considered a member of that race:

> Every humanoid creature also has a subtype to match its race, such as
> human, giant, goblinoid, reptilian, or tengu. If you are making a new
> humanoid race, you should either find an existing subtype to match or
> make a new one by using the name of the race as the subtype. If you
> are making a halfbreed race, it should have the racial type of both
> parent races. For example, a half-elf has both the human and the elf
> subtypes. Subtypes are often important to qualify for other racial
> abilities and feats. **If a humanoid has a racial subtype, it is
> considered a member of that race in the case of race prerequisites.**

This means that you can qualify for a race's FCB as long as you are a Humanoid with that race's subtype. For example, a [Drow](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Drow) qualifies for the Elf FCB because Drow are "Humanoids" with the "Elf" subtype. Similarly, the [Duergar](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Duergar) are "Humanoids (Dwarf)" and qualify for the Dwarf FCB, the [Hobgoblins](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Hobgoblin) are "Humanoids (Goblinoid)" and qualify for the Goblin FCB, and so forth.

So if you give your custom humanoid race a racial subtype (e.g. Tengu), then characters with that race qualify for racial abilities & feats as if they were a member of that race (e.g. for the Tengu FCB).